# My HDD not showing up in Ubuntu(22.10)

Tags: boot, hard-drive, 22.10

Hi I'm very new to Ubuntu, and I tried searching for this problem but couldn't find any suitable solution.

I have two disks in my machine. I wiped windows and installed Ubuntu. I didn't do anything extra while installing just followed [the reccomended installation procedure](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-drive-management). I chose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and didn't set up encryption.
I can't seem to access the other disk.It doesn't show in Disk Usage Analyzer.

It doesn't show in the ubuntu command line.

Edit: Hey matigo, I tried `sudo lsblk -f` and got this:

```
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│    vfat   FAT32       D80D-C48D                             504.9M     1% /boot/efi
└─sda2
     ext4   1.0         6bb4ca7d-2460-43d5-8a2d-7458e13e75f4  407.7G     6% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                            /
```

also: for`sudo fdisk -l | grep sd` (probs just the same thing, but sorry no idea)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to show the output of this command: `sudo lsblk -f`. This will show all storage devices in the machine as well as their file systems and mount points 

Comment: Editting the post somehow messed up the images, sorry. 

Comment: Silly question, but does the other disk appear in your system's UEFI/BIOS? Is it a SATA device or is it NVMe? 

Comment: @matigo I'm sorry, I've no idea. How can I check that? It used to work alright with windows and I just installed Ubuntu so I'm not sure. Also how can I check if the "other disk appear in your system's UEFI/BIOS"? I'm so sorry that I don't know these things.

Comment: I did a hardware diagnostics in UEFI and came okay

Comment: hi @matigo lspci shows a SATA controller, did you mean that?